MERN app deployed on Vercel, 404 when i refresh sub domain
I have a quite specific issue that I can't seem to resolve: When I reach my MERN app deployed on Vercel, everything works fine until I try to refresh a page other than the homepage (all subpages). I should mention that I have a context providing data to my entire application. The problem seems to be with the redirects because when I refresh, for example, my page "mysite/composers/music", I get a 404 error.
Here's my vercel.json:
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }]
}

Here's my App.tsx:
function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <ComposersProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <GlobalStyle />
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
              <Route path='/categories' element={<Categories />} />
              <Route
                path='/composers/music'
                element={<Composers category='music' />}
              />
              <Route
                path='/composers/cinema'
                element={<Composers category='cinema' />}
              />
              <Route
                path='/composers/videogame'
                element={<Composers category='videogame' />}
              />
              <Route path='/add-composer' element={<AddComposer />} />
              <Route path='/modify-composer/:id' element={<ModifyComposer />} />
              <Route path='/suggest-composer' element={<SuggestComposer />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ComposersProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

I have an "app" folder in my backend, which contains my "index.js" :
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const errorHandler = require("../middleware/errorHandler");
const composersRoutes = require("../routes/composers");
const mailRoutes = require("../routes/mail");
const userRoutes = require("../routes/user");

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["https://my-personnal-site.vercel.app"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.json({ limit: "5mb" }));

const connectDB = () => {
  mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Connection OK !");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Failed to connect to MongoDB", error);
      process.exit(1);
    });
};

connectDB();

app.use("/composers", composersRoutes);
app.use("/auth", userRoutes);
app.use("/mail", mailRoutes);

app.use(errorHandler);

module.exports = app;

I should mention that everything works fine locally: I can refresh all pages without any issues.
Thanks in advance to those who will read this, feel free to ask me for more details, any help is greatly appreciated!
I've tried several changes in my vercel.json, as I suspect the issue must lie within this file since it works locally... When I try to directly access "my-personnal-site.vercel.app/composers/music", I expect my ComposersContext to provide the necessary data for displaying my page ".../composers/music", but is this where the problem lies? Considering my vercel.json, I redirect all requests to /api, is this the right thing to do? I've tried redirecting to index.html as I've read in many articles and forums, but in that case, my "getcomposers" request at the enter of my app, which fetches my data in the ComposersContext, fails to succeed...
